# Elementor: Custom Show & Hide Sections Not Working In Some Browsers

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide, elementor

Having a problem on a site created using Elementor. In particular, I have functioning show/hide feature, but it only works on Firefox and I need it to work on all of 'em.

URL: https://designrv.com.au/evx/#evx-floorplan

For context, I used a "Show/Hide Sections" tutorial from the following site: https://wpjunction.net/elementor-show-hide-sections

Instead of buttons (as per tutorial) to show/hide sections, I'm using a HTML  element to show/hide 4 containers, each with a floorplan image + text specs:
choose an option from the select box to show a different floorplan/spec (note: there are four different floorplan/spec sections in total - 1 always showing, 3 always hidden), etc...

Followed the tutorial (link as above) almost to the letter — instead of using buttons, I assigned the buttons' IDs to each  and the class "drv_container_hidden" to all sections.

Then added the CSS for hiding sections:

```
<style> 
.elementor-editor-active .drv_container_hidden{ 
    display:block; 
} 
.drv_container_hidden{ 
    display:none; 
} 
.shown{ 
    display: block !important; 
} 
</style>
```

And then the JavaScript for controlling behavior:

```
<script> 
    // replace with your button IDs 
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1"); 
    var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2"); 
    var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
    var btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4"); 
     //Click Event Handlers for buttons 
    btn1.onclick = function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        toggleDivs("sect1"); 
    }; 
    btn2.onclick = function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        toggleDivs("sect2"); 
    }; 
    btn3.onclick = function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        toggleDivs("sect3"); 
    };
    btn4.onclick = function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        toggleDivs("sect4"); 
    }; 
    //function to hide or show 
    function toggleDivs(s){ 
        //reset
        document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
        document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
        document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
        document.getElementById("sect4").classList.remove("shown");
        document.getElementById(s).classList.add("shown"); 
    } 
    btn1.focus(); //force first button to focus
    btn1.click(); //force first button to click

</script>
```

In the end...

Got it working using Firefox:
[working show/hide feature in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWcsK.gif)

Chrome & Safari: the show/hide feature doesn't work (i.e. switching to a new option in the select box does not change the floorplan/specs:
[not working show/hide feature in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLwlP.gif)
No idea if it works on Windows browsers — I assume it doesn't.

As per Elementor Support's instructions, I disabled all plugins - except for Elementor - turning on one-by-one, yet, the problem still persists.
Support took a deeper look into the problem: found some "bug" in the code, however, they wouldn't elaborate (violates policy/rules).
Didn't get a response from the author from the original tutorial page.
Also posted the problem on facebook's Elementor Community, but nobody responded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your "onclick" event is not activating when you change options. Instead, you could do something like this in your JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById("modSelect");
select.onchange = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // add one because the index will start at 0
    // note that in this context, "this" is the select element itself
    var btnNum = this.selectedIndex + 1;

    toggleDivs("sect" + btnNum);
}
```

This function will fire everytime the user changes the option currently selected (even if they do it while keyboard navigating, wich would not happen with the onclick event even in firefox), then get the selectedIndex, wich basically is the index of the selected element, starting from 0. I added one into it because your btns start at 1. Then we simply call the toggleDivs function normally. Note that the `option` element is *not* a button, so your naming of the variables is confusing, wich could lead to misunderstanding of your question.